# My Jmeter scenario doesn't loop with thread-group

Tags: automated-testing, tools, load-testing, jmeter, stress-testing

I'm not so new to Jmeter.But my scenario doesn't loop if I set loopCount or set endless loop in ThreadGroup.
It just does onetime loop and stop testing without any errors.

Usually I can make a scenario does loop.
I attached below the bad jmx and good jmx as a zipfile on google drive.

There's defference in those two jmx.
NotWorking one is for https-website,Working one is for http-website.
But even I change the NotWorking one to http,it won't work.
I can't tell what's wrong.
Could you tell me what makes 'onetime-loop'?

Here is a zip of the [scenario](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4IF7DdibOyWNU9pbThGV0FtUjQ/view?usp=sharing).
Thanks,in advance.

---

I found it by myself.
Still I'm not sure but there's difference in jmx.
That's not controled by GUI setting(maybe).
Specifically,LoopControlPanel's "LoopController.continue_forever" value is different,true or false.

What makes this difference???

Comment: I realize there're diferrences.Good one,I add ThreadGroup->LogicControler(LoopControler)->Element.Bad one,It' exported from BadBoy.After exporting,so there's Element already,I add ThreadGroup and LogicControler.I guess the process make difference in JMX.